# How to run Outliner operations for 3D view selection?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, operator, outliner

How can I run an `outliner` operation based on the user's `3D View` objects selection?

Technically: how does the `3D View` selection relate to the `Outliner Selection`, and how can Python work with them?

*My current problem:* the operation I need to run is `bpy.ops.outliner.id_operation(type='OVERRIDE_LIBRARY)` seems not to have an object operation available, so I was wondering If I can let the user select the objects in the `3D View`, and run a command from the `3D view` which performs `Outliner` operations.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "outliner operations"? The outliner is primarily used for showing objects in a scene, and details about them. I.e. animated parts, animated textures, vertex groups, etc.

Comment: That's what makes no sense for me, if is for showing objects, why some operations must be performed, with a selection there, not blender ``data`` and some operation over it. For example to add a ``library override`` ``bpy.ops.outliner.id_operation(type='OVERRIDE_LIBRARY)`` , seems like there is no other way to do it than call the operator selecting the object in the ``outliner`` (having the mouse over the ``outliner`` region). There is way to perform the operation (seems like it) from a selection of objects from ``bpy.data`` for example.